# How to move the List of Figures to the end of a document

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

Is it possible to set the list of figures to appear at the end of a document instead of appearing at the beginning?

I tried to set

```
\listoftables
```

befor the command

```
\end{document}
```

but nothing happend.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]
{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{graphicx} %%Zum Laden von Grafiken
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\input{PDFInfos.tex}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\title{Title}

\maketitle                      % Titelei wird erzeugt

\tableofcontents            % Inhaltsverzeichnis

%% The Text %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frontmatter                    % Vorspann (z.B. römische Seitenzahlen)
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Einleitung}

\section{Motivation}
\label{sec:Motivation}

\section{Zielsetzung}
\label{sec:Zielsetzung}

\section{Aufbau der Arbeit}
\label{sec:AufbauDerArbeit}



Bei der Book-Klasse des KOMA-Script wird durch den Gliederungsbefehl    
\verb#\frontmatter# automatisch auf römische Seitennummerierung 
gewechselt und die Nummerierung der Kapitel unterdrückt. In der Regel 
sollte der Vorspann nur aus einem Kapitel -- dem Vorwort -- bestehen.

Der Vorspann endet für scrbook, wenn durch \verb#\mainmatter# der 
Hauptteil beginnt.

\mainmatter                     % Hauptteil
%\setpartpreamble[Position][Breite]{Text}
\setpartpreamble[u, r][6cm]{Dies ist ein Beispiel für eine Part-Präambel.}

\part[]{Hauptteil}
\chapter{Konzept/Aufgabenstellung}

\input{2_Konzept_Aufgabenstellung.tex}


\chapter{Fachliches Umfeld}
\input{3_Fachliches_Umfeld.tex}

\chapter{Anforderungsdefinition/Pflichtenheft}
\label{sec:AnforderungsdefinitionPflichtenheft}

\input{4_Anforderungsdefinition_Pflichtenheft}

\chapter{Entwurf}
\label{sec:Entwurf}

\input{5_Entwurf.tex}


\chapter{Realisierung}
\label{sec:Realisierung}

\input{6_Realisierung}


\chapter{Inbetriebnahme/Einsatz}
\label{sec:InbetriebnahmeEinsatz}

\input{7_Inbetriebnahme}

\chapter{Test}
\label{sec:TestInbetriebnahmeEinsatz}

\input{8_Test}


\chapter{Zusammenfassung und Ausblick}
\label{sec:ZusammenfassungUndAusblick}

\input{9_Zusammenfassung_und_Ausblick}

\chapter{Schlusswort}
\label{sec:Schlusswort}



\chapter{Diktum}

Übrigens wird ohne weitere Angaben ein Drittel der aktuellen Textbreite verwendet. Wie fast alles bei der Verwendung von \LaTeX , kann diesnatürlich angepasst werden. Wie das geht und auch alles andere zur Verwendung von Präambeln steht im scrguide 3.\,6.\,2.


\appendix                           % Beginn des Anhangs
\chapter{Schluss}

Für den Schluss ist zu überlegen, wie man den Anhang formatiert haben möchte: Das KOMA-Script kennt den Befehl \verb#\backmatter#. Hierdurch wird die Nummerierung der Gliederungseinheiten im Text und im Inhaltsverzeichnis unterdrückt. Erwartet man die übliche Beschriftung mit "`Anhang A"' bzw. "`A."' so verwendet man den Befehl \verb#\appendix# und verzichte auf \verb#\backmatter# oder setze es zu einem späteren Punkt ein.

Viel Spaß! Für Rückfragen, die diese Vorlage betreffen, stehe ich Ihnen gern in der Mailingliste von TXC zur Verfügung. Ansonsten sind die Dokumente \texttt{lshort}, \texttt{l2tabu}, die \texttt{FAQ der Newsgroup de.text.tex} und natürlich der \texttt{scrguide} immer sehr hilfreich.

%\backmatter                    % Nachspann 

%% Bibliographie unter Verwendung von dinnat %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\setbibpreamble{Präambel}      % Text vor dem Verzeichnis
%\bibliographystyle{dinat}
%\bibliography{bibliographie}   % Sie benötigen einen *.bib-Datei

\pagenumbering{roman}
%% Erzeugung von Verzeichnissen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\listoftables               % Tabellenverzeichnis
\listoffigures              % Abbildungsverzeichnis

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE (you should use the `mwe` package to provide a functioning MWE)? Also note that you are more likely to be looking for the `\listoffigures` command.

Comment: The `\listof....` and `\tableofcontents` commands can be placed basically anywhere between `\begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: It takes two runs.  It sort of goes without saying, but it is really a list of table captions.  Any table without a \caption will be ignored.

Comment: @Richard You do not need the `mwe` package for an MWE. I have, in fact, never seen an MWE which required `mwe` to be loaded. *Some* MWEs use images from the package, but it is not necessary to load the package, and there are other acceptable substitutes e.g. rules or `demo` mode for `graphicx`.

Comment: @cfr you are of course right, but it adds simplicity for basic questions regarding figures.

Comment: Did everything work as expected when you moved `\listoffigures` instead of/in addition to `\listoftables`?

Comment: @Richard Using the images does. Using the package doesn't really.

Comment: @cfr - If you have NEVER loaded the MWE package, you can't use the images.  There is a first time for everyone.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't understand your comment. Are you sayig that you have to load the `mwe` package in order to use the images or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @JohnKormylo you have to install package `MWE` on your computer. Then you can use it without command `\usepackage{mwe}` in your tex file.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I've never loaded it and I use the images all the time. Of course, it is installed, but I've never loaded it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that's what I have done. But the list doesn't apear in the end of the document, after the (main) text.

Comment: @Doan: After the main text? I hope you don't mean after `\end{document}`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no, I mean before \end{document' :)

Comment: @Doan: Well, you say you have done this, but you did not provide a MWE. What shall we do in this case?

Comment: Correction:  If you have never INSTALLED the MWE package, you can't use the images.  I apologize for the sloppy terminology.  (Also, I usually auto-install packages.)

Comment: 3 Upvotes for an incomplete question?

Comment: now the n the posting is a example. Ist not MWE, but the code, that I am Using

Comment: @Doan: Yes, it's the code, but not working, since there files like `PDFinfo` we can't use. If I change to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and comment the various `\input` calls, then I can compile the document... and, guess what, the `List of Figures` is a the end!

Comment: Are there any news here?